# Print string with spaces which complete it to requested length - Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7 and I want to print a variable which its length is unknown, with spaces which complete the string to requested length.

Example of how it is done in Python 3.7 using f-strings:

```
print(f"{variable:<20}")
```

The 2.7 version doesn't support f-strings. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Use the `.format()` method, it supports it.

Comment: http://pyformat.info

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Python 2.7? Python 3 has been around for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, you can use `str.format`.

```
variable = 'hello'
"{:<20}".format(variable)
# 'hello               '
```

Or:

```
"%-20s" % variable
# 'hello               '
```

If you prefer to do it the hard way.

```
def pad(s, width):
  if len(s) < width:
    return s + ' ' * (width - len(s))
  else:
    return s

pad(variable, 20)
# 'hello               '
```